# Have PartCover include an assembly with "System" in name

Tags: mstest, partcover

I am trying to use the PartCover (v.2.3.0.36319) to measure code coverage on assemblies from unit tests run in MSTest. I can get successful reports on all assemblies except one named SystemLogger. Ive tried these rules:

```
+[SystemLogger]*
+[*]*
+[System*]*
```

None of these will force PartCover to include that dll. Looking at the run log, I noticed there seems to be a couple of built in excludes:

```
Exclude [mscorlib]*
Exclude [System*]*
```

I never specified either one of these, but it seems reasonable to say its preventing my dll from being included. Is there some way to force PartCover to include my assembly *without* renaming it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with PartCover - you should raise the issue with the PartCover team.

Oh look you have :)

https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4/issues/47

Comment: PartCover has now been patched to use the same filters used by OpenCover the defaults are now
-[mscorlib]*,
-[System]* and -[System*]*

Comment: what I meant to say was -[mscorlib]\*, -[System]\* and -[System.\*]\*